# instance type on inyected services in IONIC 2

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic2

I want to know how injected's services works on IONIC 2. Specifically, I want to know how many instances will be exists if one service is used in two or more controllers.

In the past, i asked to a collegue, and he tell me that IONIC 2 works with singleton pattern, but in my test, i think it does not.

I have two controllers, A and B; and one service SVC1. Is something like that.

Controller A

```
import { NavController, Platform } from 'ionic-angular';
import { PageB } from '../pageb/pageB';
import { SVC1 } from '../../providers/svc1';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-a',
  templateUrl: 'a.html',
  providers: [SVC1]
})

export class PageA {
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, platform: Platform, public svc: SVC1) {
  }

onAddEventClicked(event): void {    
  this.navCtrl.push(PageB);
  }
}
```

Controller B

```
import { NavController, Platform } from 'ionic-angular';
import { SVC1 } from '../../providers/svc1';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-b',
  templateUrl: 'b.html',
  providers: [SVC1]
})

export class PageB {
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, platform: Platform, public svc: SVC1) {
  }
}
```

Service

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
@Injectable()
export class SVC1 {
  constructor(public http: Http) { 
    console.log('creating another instance');
  }
}
```

This is very very simple. PageA has a button. When click it, it go to PageB. PageA and PageB use the same service.

If this service were singleton, the message "creating another instance" will be appears only once. But it's appearing two times.

Why occur this? IONIC use singleton pattern to inyect service reference? Is there a way to have onlye one instance of my service?

Thanks a lot

PS: Sorry for my bad english, hopefully I will improve with more time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have set your service as provider for each individual page.This is not the singleton pattern. This is used when you need the service available for only that component.

For singleton pattern,you set it as provider in NgModule in app.module.ts.

```
@NgModule({
 declarations:[..]
 imports:[..],
 bootstrap:[IonicApp],
 entryComponents:[...],
 providers:[SVC1] //here
})
export class AppModule { }
```

and then add the service in the constructor of any components you need.
[here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/dependency-injection.html#!#angular-dependency-injection)
Angular Official docs has information regarding the dependency injection